# IE - JQuery appending child nodes to XML in $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem with IE not correctly appending or recognizing my attempts to append child nodes into a parsed XML string. Chrome and Firefox understand what I'm attempting to do. I don't know if this is a scope issue or a behavior of IE and XML.

```
var dataContainers = $('[data-container]');
var containerXML = $.parseXML('<inlineSubmission><userid>'+userID+'</userid><guid>'+GUID+'</guid><contentField><![CDATA[FlexXML]]></contentField><content><containers></containers></content></inlineSubmission>');

$.each(dataContainers,function (key,value) {
var containerID = $(value).attr('id'),
        isVisible = $(value).is(':visible'),
        xmlFragment;

xmlFragment = '<container><name>'+containerID+'</name><visible>'+isVisible+'</visible></container>';

$(containerXML).find('containers').append(xmlFragment);
});

console.log(containerXML)
```

Chrome and Firefox both correctly return:

```
<inlineSubmission><userid>55555</userid><guid>22222-222-2-22-222</guid><contentField><![CDATA[FlexXML]]></contentField><content><containers><container><name>heroContainer</name><visible>true</visible><bgcolor>undefined</bgcolor><textcolor>undefined</textcolor><subitem><name>contactInfo</name><visible>none</visible><location>undefined</location></subitem></container><container><name>contentContainer</name><visible>true</visible></container><container><name>cnmContainer</name><visible>true</visible></container><container><name>accountAccessContainer</name><visible>true</visible></container><container><name>promoContainer</name><visible>true</visible></container><container><name>contactContainer</name><visible>true</visible></container></containers></content></inlineSubmission>
```

While IE is returning the original variable value:

```
<inlineSubmission><userid>55555</userid><guid>22222-222-2-22-222</guid><contentField><![CDATA[FlexXML]]></contentField><content><containers /></content></inlineSubmission>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `console.log($(containerXML).find('containers').length)` before you assume the append is the problem.

Comment: Also, you seem to be appending HTML into an XML document. IE might not like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting `$(containerXML.documentElement)` for `$(containerXML)` .

---

`$(containerXML)` returns `#document` , having `context` of `document` , e.g.;

`$(document).append("<p>abc</p>")`

would not append `<p>abc</p>` to `<html>` or `<body>` elements , and may return error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null` .

---

`$(containerXML.documentElement)` returns `<inlinesubmission>` element , having `context` of `inlinesubmission`

```js
var userID = "abc", GUID = 123, containerID = 456, isVisible = true;

var xmlFragment = '<container><name>'
                  +containerID+'</name><visible>'
                  +isVisible+'</visible></container>';

var containerXML = $.parseXML('<inlineSubmission><userid>'
                              +userID+'</userid><guid>'
                              +GUID+'</guid><contentField><![CDATA[FlexXML]]>'
                              +'</contentField><content><containers></containers>'
                              +'</content></inlineSubmission>');

console.log($(containerXML)
            , $(containerXML.documentElement).find("containers"));

$(containerXML.documentElement).find("containers").append(xmlFragment);

$("body").append($(containerXML.documentElement));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. Thanks for the answers! They gave me the right direction to move in:

```
var containerXML = $('<inlineSubmission><userid>'+userID+'</userid><guid>'+GUID+'</guid><contentField>FlexXML</contentField><content><containers></containers></content></inlineSubmission>');

$.each(dataContainers,function (key,value) {
var containerID = $(value).attr('id'),
    isVisible = $(value).is(':visible'),
    xmlFragment;

xmlFragment = $('<container><name>'+containerID+'</name><visible>'+isVisible+'</visible></container>')

$(containerXML).find('containers').append(xmlFragment);
});

var parsedXML = $.parseXML(containerXML[0].outerHTML);
console.log(parsedXML)
```