# jQuery - On appending child node using append()- appended xml tags are converted to lowercase in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing, internet-explorer-11

**Problem statement:**

I'm trying to append a child node to a parent XML node using append() using jQuery in IE browser.
On trying, I found that append() wouldn't add any elements into the XML node and the child nodes were returned empty.

On troubleshooting, I found that this is a known issue for IE and I found this post here - [IE - JQuery appending child nodes to XML in $.each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832327/ie-jquery-appending-child-nodes-to-xml-in-each-loop).

On using the solution suggested in this post, I'm now able to append the child node to the parent node. **However, the XML tags of the child node are all appended in lowercase as shown below:**

**Current result:**

```
<Content>
     <ParentNode>
          <childrennode>
               <child1>true</child1>
               <child2>Hello</child2>
          </childrennode>
     </ParentNode>
</Content>
```

**Expected result**

```
<Content>
     <ParentNode>
          <ChildrenNode>
               <Child1>true</Child1>
               <Child2>Hello</Child2>
          </ChildrenNode>
     </ParentNode>
</Content>
```

```js
var contentXML =('<Content><ParentNode></ParentNode></Content>');
var node = $.parseXML(contentXML)
var nodeXML = $(node).find('Content > ParentNode');
var value1 = true;
var value2 = "Hello";
var childNodeinIE = $('<ChildrenNode><Child1>' + value1 + '</Child1>'+ '<Child2>'+ value2 +'</Child2>'+'</ChildrenNode>');
nodeXML.append(childNodeinIE);
console.log($(nodeXML).find("Content > ParentNode > ChildrenNode").text());
console.log($(nodeXML).find("Content > ParentNode > childrennode").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I understand that I could also use:

```
 $(contentXML).find("Content > ParentNode > ChildrenNode > Child1").text(value1);
```

However, I want to append it and do not want to override the values.

Can someone please suggest how to retain the XML tags as shown in the expected result, please?.

Comment: Hi, Can you please fix your code snippet first? I don't see anything from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i have been using jQuery to parse XML but it doesnt maintain uppercase. Is there a flag im missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384034/i-have-been-using-jquery-to-parse-xml-but-it-doesnt-maintain-uppercase-is-there)

Comment: I've updated the snippet. The issue is now reproducible.

Comment: @freedomn-m, looks like the solution in the suggested post works for Chrome but not in IE, unfortunately. :(

Comment: As per linked answer: you've changed your first contentXML to $.parseXML - but your *second* `$('<ChildrenNode><Child1>' + value1` is still parsing by jquery as *HTML*, so will be lower case.  As you're using `.append(childNode)` immediately, it doesn't need to be a jquery object, so change to `var childNodeinIE = '<ChildrenNode><Child1>'` (without the jquery parsing as HTML) and it works fine.

Comment: Your code also doesn't work in my version of Chrome.  Also note that latest versions of "IE" and Chrome use the same engine - so when you say "not in IE" you'll need to include version and if it's IEdge the version as well.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your inputs. In IE when I do the changes as follows, it does not append anything. The child nodes are not appended. However, it definitely appends the child node in chrome and the format is retained as well.
var childNodeinIE = '<ChildrenNode><Child1>' + value1 + '</Child1>'+ '<Child2>'+ value2 +'</Child2>'+ '<Child3>'+ value3 +'</Child3>'+'</ChildrenNode>'
nodeXML.append(childNodeinIE);

Comment: Well, in *my* IEdge, it works fine (91.0) using `nodeXML.append(string)` - and now I have a bad taste in my mouth from having to open IE to check.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for testing :) Appreciate it. The application that I'm testing is using Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: I made tests with your code snippet in IE 11 and Chrome, but the results are the same. You can check: [result in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtylM.png), [result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wpbk.png). It seems that they're both lowercase in IE 11 and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work in IE, I had to use appendTo().

Eg:

```
childNodeinIEXML = $($.parseXML(childNodeinIE)).find("ChildrenNode");
childNodeinIEXML.appendTo(nodeXML)
```